# How could be the rotation in odd and even dimension spaces?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, rotations

I am studying the rotation in the space. I am wondering there is any relation between the rotation and the dimension of the space?

For example, in the case of odd dimensions the rotation is around the origin while in the even dimensions the rotations is around one axes!

Or maybe in spaces with odd dimensions we have rotation around some plane of odd dimensions and in spaces with even dimensions we have rotation around planes of even dimensions!

Indeed, my goal is to see which are the curves $\gamma(t)$ where $\gamma(t)=\alpha(t)Rot(a_1t,...,a_kt)$. Here $\alpha(t)$ is a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and \begin{equation}
Rot(a_1t,...,a_kt)=\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
R(a_1t)\oplus ...\oplus R(a_kt)\oplus 1 &\hspace{4mm} \text{if} & n=2k\\
R(a_1t)\oplus ...\oplus R(a_kt) \hspace{7mm} &\hspace{4mm} \text{if} &n=2k-1,
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
R(a_it)=
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos a_it & \sin a_it \\
 -\sin a_it & \cos a_it \\
 \end{array} } \right).
\end{equation}

Comment: There are rotations in $\mathbb{R}^4$ which are not around a single axis, for example consider two rotations of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of different angles, put together on orthogonal subspaces of dimension 2.

Comment: For me a rotation of an  $n$-dimensional space is a rotation around an $(n-2)$-dimensional subspace. Arguably we could call those "simple rotations", and call any orientation and distance preserving linear transformation (i.e. an element of $SO(\Bbb{R},n)$) "a rotation". Anyway, an odd/even dichotomy that will always be present for such orthgonal transformations is that in odd dimensions they always have an axis (=an eigenspace belonging to eigenvalue $1$). In even dimensions you can construct orthogonal transformations that move all the points.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Let me put some more explanation into my question to make it more clear!

Comment: You can always define rotation around a bivector in both even and odd dimensions. In even dimensions bivectors are planes in odd-dimensions they are also planes with a dual-space of odd dimension normal to the plane